# Issue with result of Microdata schema.org in Google Labs

Tags: microdata

Please note this code:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<head>
  <meta itemprop="name" content="webpage"/>
</head>

<body>
  <div itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
      <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4">
      <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="0">  
      <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5">                  
      <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="100">
    </span>
  </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

If I add an `AggregateRating` inside the `div` tag for article, Google Labs does not show the values of `AggregateRating` on its URL result So I must remove `itemprop="mainContentOfPage"` or add `AggregateRating` out of the `div` tag or add both.

How can I fix this problem?

`AggregateRating` belongs to `AggregateRating`, not `WebPage`!?

For a solution I changed the code to this:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<head>
  <meta itemprop="name" content="webpage"/>
</head>

<body>
  <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
      <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4">
      <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="0">  
      <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5">                  
      <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="100">
    </span>

  <div itemprop="about mainContentOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
      <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4">
      <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="0">  
      <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5">                  
      <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="100">
    </span>
  </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

But I'm not sure it's true or not!

Comment: Have you tried using google labs to test it? if it works then its right. If you have answered your own question, please remove it from the question and click answer this question yourself.

Comment: NO,I think google lab can not recognize that. You can use each property for any Things and google lab do not return any error!

Comment: search appearance > structured data?

Comment: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Comment: whats your site?

Comment: I'm on localhost

Comment: how are you testing with lab if your using localhost?

Comment: We can copy/paste source code on goolge lab. :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I understand that the schema.org markup is confusing and I am hardly an expert.

I removed a few items that did not make sense to me and changed your meta statements to spans. I noticed in answering a previous question that the meta statements do not work. I recommend using span instead.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
      <span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span>
      <span itemprop="worstRating">0</span> 
      <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>
      <span itemprop="ratingCount">100</span>
    </span>
  </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works in the Google Rich Snippets Tool okay.

The AggregateRating could optionally be followed by Review to list some or all of the reviews if you want.

Comment: Thanks for The answer...But HTML tag has this Microdata: "<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">" and I do not want remove it!

Comment: I am not stopping you. Go for it! I took it out because it clouded the AggregateRating when testing it which I was assuming was not working as you expected. AggregateRating is nested within Article within my sample. Schema.org markup can get a bit hinky from time to time. When you re-add WebPage, just be sure to watch the nesting to make sure there is no confusion.